# How up upgrade Windows 10 v1511 to v1607?

Tags: windows, upgrade

I'm trying to replicate a bug that is happening on a client's machine to a local VM.  Their machine is running Windows 10 v1607.  I have a ISO containing v1511.  Is there a way to upgrade that version to v1607?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't upgrade an ISO, if that's what you mean.  You would need to obtain a v1607 ISO from Microsoft, which (assuming that you are a software developer) would typically be done via an MSDN subscription.  Or I guess you could look for a retail boxed copy second-hand or something.

If you have a Windows Server, another option would be to install WSUS on the server, install v1507 on your client VM, and then use WSUS to upgrade the VM to v1607.  There's a fair bit of work involved there, but it would be doable.

Comment: Yeah, I've come to realise this.  I've already asked my IT department to get the required ISO.  Thanks.